# Why there are line breaks when PutAppend a string to file?

Tags: export, output-formatting

When I tried to putappend a string to a file, I found that in the text there were strange line breaks like:

```
"\:5927\:79e6\:94c1\:8def,6.190,6.230,6.180,6.220,6.170,6.180,6.190,20683205,\
127957575.000,571122,6.180,1405356,6.170,399300,6.160,686900,6.150,151300,6.1\
40,403200,6.190,337000,6.200,790543,6.210,514700,6.220,523200,6.230,2016-09-1\
4,15:00:00"
```

It was really disturbing. Can anyone give a solution?

Comment: It appears to be adding line breaks for a long string.  If you copy and paste the string into the front end you'll notice that the line breaks disappear.

Answer (score 8):

The backslash at the end of a line indicates that expression is continued at the next line (and there is no actual linebreak). They are added due to the default option `PageWidth -> 78` of `OpenAppend`:

```
Options[OpenAppend, PageWidth]
```

> ```
> {PageWidth -> 78}
> ```

In *Mathematica* version <10 and starting from version 11.3 setting this option to `Infinity` solves the problem:

```
SetOptions[OpenAppend, PageWidth -> Infinity]
```

In versions 10.0 - 11.3 this method doesn't work due to a bug (fixed in 11.3). So you should write your own `PutAppend`, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6441361/590388):

```
Clear[myPutAppend]
myPutAppend[expr_, pathtofile_String] :=
 (Write[#, expr]; Close[#];) &[OpenAppend[pathtofile, PageWidth -> Infinity]]
```

Answer (score 6):

[`Put`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Put.html) and [`PutAppend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PutAppend.html) are for exporting *Mathematica* expressions, where line breaks with continuations are inconsequential.  Your needs are likely better served by other tools such as [`WriteString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WriteString.html).  No line breaks appear in the output file created here:

```
x = Range @ 100;
y = Alphabet[];
WriteString["linebreaktest.txt", x, y]
```

The file contents, abridged:

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7... 96, 97, 98, 99, 100}{a, b, c, d, e, f... v, w, x, y, z}

Don't forget to [`Close`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Close.html) the file after you are done:

```
Close["linebreaktest.txt"]
```

Comment: +1 for explaining why `Put` is not the right choice.  I don't think `Close` is necessary when using a file name (and not a stream) in `WriteString`.  But to *append* to an existing file, we must first explicitly open it using `str = OpenAppend[...]`, write to `str`, then finally `Close[str]`.  Just using a file name in `WriteString` won't append.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the vote.  It seems we have uncovered a version/platform dependence that we should map.  In *Mathematica* 10.1.0 under Windows 7 x64 `WriteString["linebreaktest.txt", x]; WriteString["linebreaktest.txt", y]` *does* append, and `Close` *is* needed to release the file.  Please, which version and platform are you using?

Comment: It's not a version difference, it's  a misunderstanding on my part. I think the documentation is misleading. I tried it and here's how it works: `WriteString["foo.txt", ...]` will overwrite `foo.txt`, not append to it.  But as you say, it doesn't close the file.  `Streams[]` reveals an open stream.  Any additional writes to this file will therefore keep appending to it, until `Close["foo.txt"]` is called.

Comment: I was looking at the WriteString examples the other day. Check the first example.  It neglects to close the file.  I'm going to submit a suggestion to change this because I find it misleading.  The other examples are fine.  You are right that `Close` is important.