# Undo added line breaks PutAppend

Tags: export, import, output-formatting

I used `PutAppend` to write away a some results. It turns out that Mathematica has inserted annoying line breaks. This is discussed in [Why there are line breaks when PutAppend a string to file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126601/why-there-are-line-breaks-when-putappend-a-string-to-file) and it offers some ways to avoid this from happening in the future. But how do I clean up the files that were already written away with the default `PutAppend`? Note there are also line breaks that are supposed to be there. Is there a good way to recognized the line breaks that Mathematica decided to add and remove them?

---

Each separate result was supposed to be printed on a newline

```
result1
result2
```

but now there are additional line breaks breaking up the results. I had thought this would make the files nice to read with `ReadList`. Now it turns out it is terrible due to the unintended line breaks.

Comment: `StringReplace[Import[file], "\"\n\"" -> "\"\""]`?

Comment: @kglr that replacement leaves the result of `Import[file]` unchanged.

(`StringReplace[Import[file], "\"\n\"" -> "\"\""]===Import[file]`  gives True.)